# Solr query still return results with stopword

Tags: solr, analyzer

I set "porn" as a stopword in my Analyzer, and it works at **Solr admin UI**, **Index** and **Query** all filter the stopword, see as below:
[Analysis screen with stop word "porn"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCwEn.png)

but when I **query** with that word, the document with such stopword still returned,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kdzC.png)

I'm confused, can anyone tell me why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does name and text_ik have same field definition. if yes

the query

```
localhost:8983/solr/cntest2/select?q=porn
```

search in default field(mostly text field)

try with field name `localhost:8983/solr/cntest2/select?q=name:porn`

Comment: Thanks so much! It works with the suggested query string "q=name:porn".  Yes, the field type of "name" is "text_ik",  is it necessary querying with a certain field to get stopword come into effect?

Comment: More question, what's the query syntax if I want to filter multiple fields?

Comment: its not like that. stopword filter works for all field where you defined. since text field is default add stopwords filter factory to text field like how you added for text_ik field. `<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />` then it should work for `localhost:8983/solr/cntest2/select?q=porn`

Comment: I hope name field is copied to text field using `copyfield` in your schema.  upvote and accept my answer if you find it useful.